# Get URL of input tag after hover on image in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am hover on image. But i want URL of input tag.

CODE:

```
<img class="prod-zoom-img" src="image.jpg>

<input style="display:none;"  data-bigimgurl="picture.png">
```

I want to hover on prod-zoom-img class but i want to get of bigimgurl.

JQUERY:

```
$("img.prod-zoom-img").hover(function () {
    ------------ ????????---------
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mouseenter()` event like following.

```js
$('img.prod-zoom-img').mouseenter(function() {
    var url = $('input').data('bigimgurl');
    alert(url);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="prod-zoom-img" src="image.jpg">
<input style="display:none;"  data-bigimgurl="picture.png">
```